# Centering Multi-Colored Text via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, colors

I am trying to center text across a window; however, the text is multi-colored. For example, "Folder: " is white and "C:\Temp" is red. Centered within the window, regardless of how big or small the window is, will be "Folder: C:\Temp" but the word "Folder: " will be white and "C:\Temp" will be red.

I know how to center the entire text, as long as it's one color.

**My Code:**

```
$Path = "C:\Temp"

Function Write-A{
 param($message) Write-Host ("{0}.{1}" -f * (([Math]::Max(0, $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width / 2) - [Math}::Floor($message.Length / 2)))), $message) -ForegroundColor DarkGray
}

Write-A "Folder: $Path"
```

That centers the text; however, it's all one color. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native PS, you will need to use 2 separate calls to Write-Host to achieve this.

```
$Path = "C:\Temp"

Function Write-A
{
 param($message)

 Write-Host -NoNewLine ("{0}{1}" -f (' ' * (([Math]::Max(0, $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width / 2) - [Math]::Floor($Message.Length / 2)))), "Folder: ") -ForegroundColor white 

 Write-Host -NoNewLine $message -ForegroundColor red

}

Write-A "$Path"
```

Luckily for us, this has actually been made quite easy with Write-Color:
https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteColor

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWriteColor/0.86

I haven't figured out how to center text with it yet but, I am sure it is possible.